# Lodash cond function typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, lodash

I have two functions and I want to call them the way it is done in Lodash.
First function
`private a(a: string, b: string) { retrun false; }`

Second function
`private b(a: string, b: number, c: boolean) { return c; }`

I want to call it like
`const func1 = lodash.cond([ [this.a, () => {}], [this.b, () => {}], ]);`
`const gfg = func1('1', '2');`

And with this call i have 2 errors
First

> Overload 2 of 2, '(pairs: CondPairUnary<string, void>[]): (Target: string) => void', gave the following error.
> Type '(a: string, b: string) => {}' is not assignable to type '(val: string) => boolean'.
> Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(pairs: CondPairUnary<string, void>[]): (Target: string) => void', gave the following error.
> Type '(a: string, b: number) => {}' is not assignable to type '(val: string) => boolean'.
> Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.

Second

> Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.
> const gfg = func1('1', '2');

Comment: I'm not sure that makes much sense - `b()` takes *three* parameters and you only pass two to the composed function via `cond`. You can probably align the arity of both `a` and `b` (you can create new function on the fly, e.g., `(x, y, z) => this.a(x, y)`), however, as of right now this doesn't have a clearly defined purpose, which makes a proper solution hard to find.

Comment: As a separate note on terminology: `a()` and `b()` here are *methods* as they exist on some object. Functions are free from such context.

Comment: Also just noticed that your functions don't even take the same types for the first two parameters, `a()` has string and string, while `b()` has string and number. Even if the arity both was the same, the types of the input are incompatible, `func1('1', '2')` is only valid for `a()` not `b()`. I think this whole approach might need to be redesigned. Also read about [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I suspect you might be attempting to solve the wrong thing.